# Industrial Music- What Happened to the Genre? Where did it Go?

Tags: genre

My absolute favorite type of music has always been industrial. Bands like Rammstein, Skinny Puppy, or My Life With the Thrill Kill Kult. Even my real-world style has been defined at it's core by such bands and their aesthetics. Why does it seem to me that all of industrial music is now only known of and enjoyed by proverbial old-heads?

Am I missing out on some new artists and tracks that carry on the style of industrial?

Comment: Genres come and go... Few bands outside mainstream pop reach world-wide fame beyond the fans of that particular genre. So Rammstein would be rare a exception there. A certain genre could be alive and thriving if you only know what artists to look for, even though you won't hear much from that genre in the mainstream media channels.